# how to change the font of this?

Tags: jquery, html

i want change the font of the id=zticker

html code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.zrssfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.vticker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#zticker').rssfeed('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml',{
        header: false,
        titletag: 'div',
        date: false,
        content: false
    }, function(e) {
        $.zazar.ticker({selector: '#zticker ul'});
    });

});
</script>
<div id="zticker"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the style file

```
#zticker
{
color:black;
font:arial;
}
```

i make some style but it dont work what can i do and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#zticker').css('font-family', 'Verdana');
    //other code
});
```

New update
Try to insert into your css this

```
.feedEntryContent{
    font-family: the font that you want;
}
```

or this:

```
.rssFeed{
        font-family: the font that you want;
    }
```

Comment: where give us example

Comment: if i add this ... what about rssfeed('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml',{

Comment: not working so can you give us another solution

Comment: edit with another solution @user2098729

Comment: :) not working try to found another solution my brother

Comment: ok i think i found a solution do you know how to remove link from rss 
?

Comment: just making the titles without links

Comment: if you have solved your problem accept the answer to help other persons if they have the same problem @user2098729

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing proper tags. You need to close the head tag and insert the body tag as well.. otherwise i don't see any reason the css ain't working.. maybe there is a !important somewhere that's overriding your css.

```
</head><body>
```

Use this to force color

```
#zticker,#zticker ul,#zticker li
{
    color:black !important;
}
```

Comment: ok thank you very much but there is another probleme how can i change the color

Comment: Is it available online somewhere ? I would be in a better situation to help !

Comment: @user2098729 As a guess i would suggest using this..

    #zticker,#zticker ul,#zticker li
    {
        color:black !important;
    }

Comment: how please explain in answer ...

Comment: Could you put your page somewhere online ?

Comment: ah sorry i will .....